# How to create sitemap dynamically in Angular 12?

Tags: angular, drupal, seo, angular12, sitemap.xml

I need to create a sitemap page as my Marketing Team requires this page for SEO purposes. They have an old website built with WordPress and it shows the following:

[image]

How can I achieve this functionality in **Angular 12**?

Answer (score 7):

You need to create the **robots.txt** and **sitemap.xml** files under the **src** folder.

> robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
Sitemap: https://yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml
```

> sitemap.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->


<url>
  <loc>https://yourdomain.com/</loc>
  <lastmod>2022-10-T10:13:39+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://yourdomain.com/about</loc>
  <lastmod>2022-10-T10:13:39+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://yourdomain.com/contact</loc>
  <lastmod>2022-10-T10:13:39+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://yourdomain.com/signin</loc>
  <lastmod>2022-10-T10:13:39+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://yourdomain.com/contact/map</loc>
  <lastmod>2022-10-T10:13:39+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.64</priority>
</url>


</urlset>
```

update the assets in **angular.json** file.

> angular.json

```
"options": {
  "outputPath": "dist/browser",
  "index": "src/index.html",
  "main": "src/main.ts",
  "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
  "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
  "assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets",
    "src/manifest.webmanifest",
    "src/sitemap.xml",
    "src/robots.txt"
  ],
```

if you want to add meta tag on page use the Meta service provided by angular to use and add meta tags

Comment: Can't we create it dynamically?

Comment: yes, we can. please check this https://pardeepjain.medium.com/how-to-create-dynamic-sitemap-xml-using-javascript-ee4d9ba7402a